# Compare instances with __eq__ why doesn't work?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't figure out why the function `createDeck` doesn't work.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rank = tk.IntVar()
        self.rank.set(rm.choice(rank))
        self.seed = tk.StringVar()
        self.seed.set(rm.choice(seeds))
        self.point = tk.IntVar()
        self.point.set(self.calculatePoint())
        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.value.set(self.calculateValue())
        self.name = tk.StringVar()
        self.name.set(self.calculateName())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.get() + ' di ' + self.seed.get()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank.get() < other.rank.get()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.rank.get() != other.rank.get() and self.seed.get() != other.seed.get()

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.rank.get() > other.rank.get()

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck= []
        self.name = tk.Label(table, text='Deck', bd=3, relief='flat')
        self.name.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def createDeck(self):
        while len(self.deck) < 40:
            x = Card()
            if x not in self.deck:
                deck.append(x)
        table.create_text(500,200, text='deck is compose by %d cards' % (len(self.deck)))
```

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method:

```
def createDeck(self):
    while len(self.deck) < 40:
        x = Card()
        if x not in self.deck:
            deck.append(x)
```

has an undefined variable `deck`.

Changing it to `self.deck`:

```
def createDeck(self):
    while len(self.deck) < 40:
        x = Card()
        if x not in self.deck:
            self.deck.append(x)
```

should be helpful.

Comment: What about the actual question *"Compare instances with `__eq__` why doesn't work?"* OP didn't mentioned that he is getting variable not initialized error. The

Comment: This seems to be the question "I can't figure out why the function 'createDeck' don't work."

Comment: you are also right. Though it is totally unclear what OP needs